# Adobe Flash Won't Install

Tags: macos, flash

I'm trying to install the latest version of Adobe Flash (15.0.0.189), but unfortunately the installer gives the rather unhelpful message that "An error has occurred" and tells me that the install won't work.

It does link here [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installation-problems-flash-player-mac.html), which also seems pretty unhelpful.  It *does* suggest uninstalling and reinstalling from scratch, but now I've done that, Flash still won't install, and now I don't have it on my system.

I'm using Mac OS 10.9.5.

Any thoughts would be welcome!

Comment: could you give me a bit more detail about what that file you've linked to is, and how it is different from the installer I was getting off Adobe?

Comment: It is straight from Adobe, but the regular installer is only a few meg & live downloads the rest once launched. That linked version [available from the very page you posted] is the entire installer, all in one file. It is usually the fix.

Comment: Excellent - I'll change this to an answer then; feel free to mark it as the correct one ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for Windows too…

Instead of using the default live, streaming installer, download the standalone installer directly from Adobe
*The link sometimes moves, see note below…*

Open the .dmg & install as you would any app.
[for Windows run the .msi or .exe of course]

It's usually the fix for the live installer getting stuck & erroring.

---

## Note

The Offline Flash installer moves around, as new versions are released.

The best way to find it is to Google "**adobe flash distribution download**" Which will usually turn up as the first hit.
As of today [2 Feb 15], that gives http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html from the UK, but YYMV.

---

Comment: Thanks! the link on [11/11/14] worked for me. Almost wasted 2 hours trying to work on it my own.